# How do I reverse the following algorithm in C

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, reverse-engineering

I have the following algorithm:

```
    unsigned long specialNum=0x4E67C6A7;
    unsigned int ch;
    char inputVal[]="                        AAPB2GXG";


    for(int i=0;i<strlen(inputVal);i++)
    {
        ch=inputVal[i];

        ch=ch+(specialNum*32);
        ch=ch+(specialNum/4);

        specialNum=bitXor(specialNum,ch);
    }

    int outputVal=specialNum;
```

The bitXor simply does the Xor operation:

```
int bitXor(int a,int b)
{
    return (a & ~b) | (~a & b);
}
```

**Now I want to reverse The Algorithm**. Given the outputVal, I want to get the inputVal.
This is what I have done till now. But it is not working :(

```
    while(outputVal!=0x4E67C6A7)
    {
        ch=bitXor(outputVal,0x4E67C6A7);

        outputVal=outputVal-(ch*4);
        outputVal=outputVal-(ch/32);
        inputVal[i++]=(char)ch;
        if(i>32)
            break;
    }
```

EDIT: Ok, agreed its not possible. But I wonder why is my question downvoted. I have followed the guidelines before posting and I dont think the question is too bad for downvoting it.

Comment: In addition to trying to get more information out than remains stored in `outputVal`, integer division isn't reversible like real number division. 0/4, 1/4, 2/4 and 3/4 all produce the same value, 0. When you multiply by 4 again, you just get 0. So you're flatten those four values into one.

Comment: About the edit: Your question is upvoted as well. and I believe the balance is positive for you..Anyway, people are free to use their votes as they will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the requested "reversed" algorithm you are asking for converting 4-byte number into an arbitrary-length string. It is obviously not possible, since assuming you are doing this, you have invented an ultimate compression algorithm.

Comment: Indeed, you basically lost information when running the first algorithm, and there is no way to get it back. Its a one-way algorithm.

Comment: It should, however, be possible to find *some* input that hashes to a given value. Basically, the OP wants to perform a collision attack on a (pretty simple) hash function. My guess would be, this is an assignment for some crypto course.

Comment: If I read the code right, the algorithm is operating only on the least significant byte of the hash, so the collision can be found in zero time manually.

Comment: How do i find a collision for this. Can you atleast point me in right direction to learn it ? I am unable to do this even after spending 6 days on it.

Comment: Sorry, I have taken a closer look at the algorithm, and it looks not as easy to find a collision as I thought at first. Some not-that-trivial analysis is required, or some kind of brute-force. But it is not changing the answer to the original question, of course.

Answer (score 2):

The "reverse algorithm" you are asking for is impossible. Your example `inputVal` is a character string over 30 letters long. Your `outputVal` is 4 or 8 bytes at best. Information theory dictates that it's impossible to store any arbitrary n-byte string into a k-byte string if n > k.

Your forward algorithm is basically bit-packing values from the array `inputVal` into the scalar variable `specialNum` in an awkward way.

Also, at the end there is an unsafe conversion from `unsigned long specialNum` to `int outputVal`.